# How to choose value in Jquery with condition?

Tags: jquery

I have code

```
var answer = $(this).data("answer");
```

I want to write so

```
 $('<div class=" if(answer="yes") {write(active)} else {write(noactive)} "></div>').appendTo(selector);
```

How to write it in Jquery?

In PHP I use "echo". How to write it in jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to understand but perhaps you want to do that :

```
var answer = $(this).data("answer");
if(answer=="yes") class="active";
else class="noactive";
$('<div class="'+class+'"></div>').appendTo(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd subtly change seorefbe's code to

```
var answer = $(this).data("answer");

$('<div></div>').addClass(answer=="yes"?"active":"noactive").appendTo(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = $(this).data("answer");
var isactive = (answer == 'yes') ? 'active' : 'noactive';
$("<div class ='"+isactive +"'...
```